# Get a deep-nested array from a mongodb aggregate and include in result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have these two collections

```
book: {
    _id: 'aaa'
    name: 'Book 1',
    chapters: [
       0: {
           _id: 'chapter0',
           name: 'Chapter 1',
           pages: [
                0: {
                    _id: 'page0',
                    name: 'Page 1',
                    paragraphs: [
                        0: {
                            _id: 'paragraph0',
                            name: 'Paragraph 1',
                            bookmarks: [
                                 0: {sentence: 3, reader: 'Foo'},
                                 1: {sentence: 8, reader: 'Bar'},
                                 2: {sentence: 14, reader: 'John'}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
           ]
       }
    ]
}



book: {
    _id: 'bbb'
    name: 'Book 2',
    chapters: [
       0: {
           _id: 'chapter0',
           name: 'Chapter 1',
           pages: [
                0: {
                    _id: 'page0',
                    name: 'Page 1',
                    paragraphs: [
                        0: {
                            _id: 'paragraph0',
                            name: 'Paragraph 1',
                            bookmarks: []
                        },
                        1: {
                            _id: 'paragraph1',
                            name: 'Paragraph 2',
                            bookmarks: [
                                 0: {sentence: 2, reader: 'George'},
                                 1: {sentence: 1, reader: 'Paul'},
                                 2: {sentence: 76, reader: 'John'},
                                 3: {sentence: 54, reader: 'Ringo'}                                 
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
           ]
       }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to extract the array `bookmarks` and attach them to the `book` collection when getting the result. Something like this would be good:

```
{
    id: 'aaa'
    name: 'Book 1'
    bookmarks: [{...}, {...}, {...}] //since the first book has 3 bookmarks
},
{
    id: 'bbb'
    name: 'Book 2'
    bookmarks: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}] //since the second book has 4 bookmarks
},
```

And if there are no bookmarks, it should look like:

```
{
    id: 'aaa'
    name: 'Book 1'
    bookmarks: [{...}, {...}, {...}] //since the first book has 3 bookmarks
},
{
    id: 'bbb'
    name: 'Book 2'
    bookmarks: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}] //since the second book has 4 bookmarks
},
{
    id: 'ccc'
    name: 'Book 3'
    bookmarks: [] //third book does not have bookmarks for example
},
```

I've tried aggregation with this code, but it just separates each bookmark per book and pushes it into the object.

```
return yield Books.aggregate()
    .unwind('chapters')
    .unwind('chapters.pages')
    .unwind('chapters.pages.paragraphs')
    .unwind('chapters.pages.paragraphs.bookmarks')
    .group({
        _id: '$_id',
        books: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$_id',
                name: '$name',
                bookmarks: '$chapters.pages.paragraphs.bookmarks'
            }
        }
    }).exec()
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below aggregate pipeline:

```
Books.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$book"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.chapters"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.chapters.pages"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$book.chapters.pages.paragraphs"
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$book.chapters.pages.paragraphs.bookmarks",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        book: "$book.name"
      },
      bookmarks: {
        $push: "$book.chapters.pages.paragraphs.bookmarks"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: No luck, it's returning the same data i've been getting which is the bookmarks are taking up the results one by one instead of being attached to the `book` object

Comment: It works but one caveat is that it's not returning the `book` field if `bookmarks` array is empty. it should still return it but with `bookmarks: []`. How can i modify the code to get that result?

Comment: add preserveNullAndEmptyArrays in last unwind then
 {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$book.chapters.pages.paragraphs.bookmarks",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },

Comment: Oh btw, you should edit your answer to reflect the comment you added here. But i already accepted it

Comment: There's one last issue though. The 'bookmarks' array is outside the `_id` object which I assume is used by $group. Is there any way to not use the `_id` object and just make it as one object that has `id`, `name` and `bookmarks`?

Comment: Edit: Nvm. i can use `$first`. Thanks for the help!